# Calabash and iOS 10

Tags: ios, calabash, calabash-ios

After being unable to launch the calabash server on iOS found out on the google group for calabash-ios [a post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-ios/g34znf0LnE4) that mentioned the following

> "Xcode 8.0 beta 2 is out and as we anticipated, UIAutomation is no longer supported.
>
> We have created a replacement called DeviceAgent that is based on Apple's XCUITest.
>
> We've already started releasing the necessary tooling to support Xcode 8 and iOS 10."

However, I don't see an update to that or the link to where i can download the tooling to support Xcode 8 and iOS 10. The GitHub repository also has nothing; anyone know where I can get this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been checking [that post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-ios/g34znf0LnE4) weekly and tried bumping it but have seen no response. At this point our team is manually testing iOS 10 and using the Xcode 8 beta, but we are unable to do anything with automation for iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

The work is incomplete but is active on both the `develop` and `feature/implement-swipe-with-device-agent` branches of [the `calabash-ios` repo](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios).

See, for example, [this commit](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/commit/f62f0cb1cdaccd4be3f2e872c30e9cb676fe82c0), which replaces `XCUITest` with `DeviceAgent`.